# strange class/trait init order in scala

Tags: scala

Why  the following code print null , instead of "Test?

```
trait Testa {
  val loginurl:String
  def fun
  val x=fun
}

class Testc extends  Testa {
  val loginurl="test"
  def fun={
    println(loginurl)
    1
  }
}

object TestTrait extends App{
  val m=new Testc()
}
```

Comment: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable `x` is initialized as part of the trait where it belongs `Testa`. At that moment, your `Testc` isn't in scope yet, therefore the method `fun` defined there cannot be used. But the variable is already bound to that method. Therefore, nothing will be printed when `Testc` is invoked.

If you change the definition of `x` from `val x = fun` to `lazy val x = fun`, by the way, and then invoke this variable after your object `m` is created, you'll see "test" printed (once). The type of x, though, will still be "Unit", as it was defined in the base trait.

```
trait Testa {
  val loginurl:String
  def fun
  lazy val x=fun
}

class Testc extends  Testa {
  val loginurl="test"
  def fun={
    println(loginurl)
    1
  }
}

scala> val testc = new Testc
testc: Testc = Testc@4106db23

scala> val testcx = testc.x
test
testcx: Unit = ()

scala> val testcx2 = testc.x
testcx2: Unit = ()
```